# PyMySQL connection timeout - code structure

Tags: python, database, performance, optimization, pymysql

I have written a script which gets data from a sqlite db to upload into MySQL db. The structure of the code is as below.

```
def insert_to_mysql(_row):
    # get mysql connection by Pymysql
    connection = pymysql.connect(..., connect_timeout=31536000)
    # insert data
    connection.close

def get_data_from_sqlite(_db):
   for i in sqlite_generator:
       insert_to_mysql(i)
```

the code works fine. But the connection get's time out without certain pattern with the below trace back very often, despite the connect_timeout in connection object and I am using one object per row. My logic is to create one object for a row so that there will not be timeout issue.

Can anyone help me in understanding what's going wrong here?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/santhosh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 691, in _read_bytes
    data = self._rfile.read(num_bytes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 575, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "up_data_upload.py", line 85, in <module>
    import_data(record)
  File "up_data_upload.py", line 43, in import_data
    db='up_scrape_data')
  File "up_data_upload.py", line 31, in get_mysql_connection
    connect_timeout=31536000)
  File "/home/santhosh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/santhosh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 325, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/home/santhosh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 598, in connect
    self._get_server_information()
  File "/home/santhosh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 975, in _get_server_information
    packet = self._read_packet()
  File "/home/santhosh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 657, in _read_packet
    packet_header = self._read_bytes(4)
  File "/home/santhosh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 699, in _read_bytes
    "Lost connection to MySQL server during query (%s)" % (e,))
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query ([Errno 110] Connection timed out)')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Handle the connect/disconnect outside the loop.

Comment: It is working. Can you explain why it is creating trouble if it is given within the loop?

Comment: The server is getting overwhelmed with connects/disconnects. This is a relatively heavy operation (even though MySQL is quite fast in this respect). I also suspect the disconnect is somewhat asynchronous, so the next connect arrives before all resources of the previous disconnect are relinguished.

Comment: It makes sense. Thanks.